# jmeter + influxdb backend: howto specify user name and password?

Tags: authentication, jmeter, influxdb

I could not find any authorization GET parameter in the influxdb docs. ( https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.5/guides/writing_data/ )

[image]

I see no way of specifying user name and password. I cannot disable authentication because the influxdb server is a live server that is public and available on the internet. I'm not able to move this server to a local machine, because I want (actually I must) run jmeter in paralel from many machines, and send all results to the same database for later aggregation.

Maybe I could setup an ssh tunnel, but that is too bad - I need to run jmeter on many machines, and it would really be painful to setup new ssh tunnels + disable influxdb auth + add firewall rules etc. during the test, then restore everything to normal, then do it again when I need to test again...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per this [doc](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.5/query_language/authentication_and_authorization/#authentication) try setting url to:

> http://127.0.0.1:8086/write?u=todd&p=influxdb4ever

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the logs on a different server :-( It works.